# Is there any reason to have both the knockout mapping plugin AND breeze?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application, durandal

I'm ramping on single page applications and it seems like Breeze automatically handles making stuff observable.  So - would it ever be necessary to use the mapping plugin if I'm using breeze to get data?

If so, can you explain the functions of both of these?

From what I understand, the knockout mapping plugin accepts and object and turns all of its properties/subproperties into observables so you don't have to manually do it.

Breeze handles data access and provides you with objects that are already observables, so the mapping plugin isn't needed.

Does this sound right?

Comment: Breeze does a lot more than that. It is a good Entity manager. The mapping plugin from knockout is an easy to use (customizable) entity mapper. Id your application plans to use Breeze for entity management (metadata and all) you don't need the mapping plugin. Use the mapping plugin when you don't want to manage dtos on the client and/or when you want extra control over how your entities are mapped. Both will work well for you, the mapping plugin solves a very specific problem, Breeze on the other hand is a bigger beast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any good reason to use the knockout mapping plugin if you are already using Breeze, unless it is to handle observables that are not managed by Breeze and that require mapping.

As you point out, Breeze adapts its entities to whichever 'modelLibrary' it is configured to use. i.e. Knockout, Angular, Backbone etc, so all of the necessary mapping will be handled by Breeze for both incoming and outgoing data.